# Maven resolving class dependencies at compile time from fatjar

Tags: maven-3

I am downloading fat jar as maven dependency. Fat jar has 2 jars inside say jar1.jar and jar2.jar. Now in my Project say P, is instantiating an object of class A which is present inside a jar1.jar which inside a fat jar, but i am getting compilation error. how can I resolve them during maven build

Comment: what error your getting can you show the stack trace?.

Comment: resolved this issue while creating fat jar added dependecies for jar1.jar and jar2.jar in pom.xml of fat.jar. Now in my project added dependency of .pom file instead of fat jar which added both jars instead of fat.jar

Comment: You can add as a answer so that will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

resolved this issue while creating fat jar. Added dependecies for jar1.jar and jar2.jar in pom.xml of fat.jar. Now in my project added dependency of .pom file instead of fat jar which added both jars instead of fat.jar. Also no need to create fat.jar